# listview column header double click event

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

Is it possible to catch the mouse double click event on a listview column header?
I handled the click event using `listView1_ColumnClick` event but I can't seem to find any way to catch a double click on it.
[image]

Comment: @MongZhu i think this answer is for wpf, tried to use it but so many references are missing.

Comment: you're right, my bad. I removed the comment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage a control which doesn't have a double click event, you can use timestamp to calculate time difference between clicks. like :

```
    DateTime lastClickDate = DateTime.Now;
    private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //You can change the value 1200 as you want.
        if ((DateTime.Now - lastClickDate).TotalMilliseconds < 1200)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("double clicked");
        }
        this.Text = (DateTime.Now - lastClickDate).TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
        lastClickDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Comment: helpful but not as quite, the next single click will trigger it no matter if it was a single or double click, although I set it to 700 ms. But thanks anyway @Coskun Ozogul

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (DateTime.Now - lastClickDate).Milliseconds instead of (DateTime.Now - lastClickDate).Milliseconds
would be better.

In addition to the previous answer I would suggest adding the position of mouse pointer. `Cursor.Position` will be helpful in this regard.

```
DateTime lastClickDate = DateTime.Now;
int xPosition = Cursor.Position.X;
int yPosition = Cursor.Position.Y;  
private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{
    //You can change the value 1200 as you want.
    if ((DateTime.Now - lastClickDate).TotalMilliseconds < 1200)
    {
        //Just for example I have given as equals it is better to allow
        //some variation since mouse may be moved a little during clicks          
        if(Cursor.Position.X==xPosition && Cursor.Position.Y==yPosition)
        {   
            MessageBox.Show("double clicked");
        } 
    }
    this.Text = (DateTime.Now - lastClickDate).TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
    lastClickDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```